# Programatically trigger click event on EmberView

Tags: ember.js, three.js

I have an Ember application and I am using three.js and its CSS renderer to display an array of views in 3D.

The problem is that once three.js does its thing, I can no longer catch a click event on the view through the controller/view or router even.

Does anyone know how to programatically trigger a click event on an Ember view? I do have access to the "data-ember-action" value and was hoping I could use this to find the binded event and have it run.

Comment: it would help to see code...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I purposely excluding any code: my question isn't aimed at solving what is happening between three.js and Ember and to do that I would have to include so much code. I just want to know if one can programatically trigger an emberView event.

Comment: ok, different try, what type of event are you interested in? Do you want to trigger an action/function on some controller from your view? Or do you need a normal event like `click` that you want to trigger inside your view?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I am just trying to capture a built in click event in the controller or view.

Comment: Do you want to trigger an event or to capture one?

Comment: I want to trigger a click event in a view,but programatically

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your last comment on capturing an event in a Ember View, this would work by simply defining a function/hook on that View with the name of the event you want to capture, something like:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(event) {
    alert("clicked!");
  },

  doubleClick: function(event) {
    alert("double clicked!");
  }
});
```

More on handling events in ember can be found in the [ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/)

Hope it helps

Comment: yeah thats what I had originally but the Three.js renderes the view divs to a Three.scene which somehow stops the click event being fired on the html node. Its like an abstraction layer is coming between the element and the window.event handler. When i dont init() the Three.js function the above works just as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you can somehow get the HTML `id` attribute for your `View` instance then you can do it using

```
Ember.View.views["#the-view-id"].click()
```

**Getting the view id**

- We can manually set `elementId` during the `View` class definition as

  ```
  Ember.View.extend({elementId: 'the-view-id'})
  ```

  Or if the Id is generated programmatically by ember, then we can use `jQuery` to get the element using class name or so and doing

  ```
  element.attr("id")
  ```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. For anyone else who accounts problems with event propagation/Ember bindings when using Three.js with Ember.js.  The problem I had was that Three.js was creating a scene and appending it to an existing DOM element:

```
renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

And in creating my Ember.Application I had given a root element:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  VERSION: '0.1.0',
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,   
  rootElement: '#column',
  ready: function() {}
});
```

Because Three.js moves the ember view into the container div, they are no longer found in the #column div where it is looking for events through the Ember.eventDispatcher.

To solve this, I just commented out the rootElement declaration.  As I had a named template and receiving {{outlet}} in the page I was rendering to, Ember could put my views into the page and without this.  When Three.js then moved the views into the #container div Ember could still watch for events on them.